# drop event not firing on backbone view

Tags: jquery, node.js, events, backbone.js, requirejs

I was happily coding and learning backbone when this #~@@! happened!

I use require to separate my views from models, etc.

In my Backbone view I handle this events:

```
define(['...'],function(...) {

var DishView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template(dish),
    tagName: 'div',
    id: 'dish',

    initialize: function() {
        console.log('initializing dishView');
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    },

    render: function(){
        console.log('rendering dishView');
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },

    events: {
        'click #relations-menu .newItem': 'launch_modal_relations',
        'click #delete' : 'delete_dish',
        'click #save-basic-changes': 'save_basic',
        'drop #dropPicture' : 'dropHandler',
        'dragenter #dropPicture' : 'alertMe'
    },

    alertMe: function () {
        console.log('clicked on image');
    },

    delete_dish: function () {
        this.model.deleteMyself();
        Backbone.history.navigate('/', {trigger: true});
    },

    save_basic: function (event) {
        var name = $('#inputName').val();
        var description = $('#inputDescription').val();
        var price = $('#inputPrice').val();
        this.model.updateBasicInfo(name, description, price);
    },

    dropHandler: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('drop received');
        event.stopPropagation();

        var e = event.originalEvent;
        e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
        this.pictureFile = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
            ...

    },
return DishView;

});
```

My drag&drop was working and suddenly when a lot of more functionality was added, it stopped working :( the image file it's opened in the browser.

I've read about the DOM being ready and that this can happen sometimes (if the code gets evaluated when the DOM is ready) **but the click events still get fired, also the dragenter event....**

Could this be some typo?? I'm going a little bit crazy I can't understand whats going on and can't remember a good commit to go back and check :S

Thank you all if you can show some possible answers :)

For example:
 - how can I debug the drop event??? 
 - how can I know if an event is tied to my view?

Comment: Also this incredible example that I follow http://nodecellar.coenraets.org/ seems that on the wine detail page I can't drop an image now, I could some days ago... am I going crazy?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're not crazy. A recent update in Google Chrome broke the drop-into-browser feature for a lot of sites, including, it seems, the NodeCellar tutorial.
This is quite easily fixable, though. Chrome now requires you to prevent the default action for the `dragover` event:

```
$('div').on('drop',function(e){
    e.originalEvent.stopPropagation();
    e.originalEvent.preventDefault();
    $(this).html('A file was dropped!');
}).on('dragover', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

This [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ejQHr/) works for me (Chrome 24.0.1312.52). Here's the [Chromium issue #168387](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=168387), about this problem.

And a [pull request to fix this in NodeCellar](https://github.com/ccoenraets/nodecellar/pull/5).

Comment: That was the best answer i could get :) Thank you so much!! How did you know about this issue?? As a dev I always think that it will be more likely to be my fault than browser's...

Comment: @Goofyahead, I didn't know about it until now. I just got curious about your comment it not working in NodeCellar and had to see for myself, because I also have some apps in production that use this feature. After that it was just a quick google search to find the Chrome bug report.

Comment: I can't express how gratefull I am :) 
I did review my code, change my functions, go to previous branches or commits... 
And I just added the preventDefault on the dragOver and happier dev ever :)

Comment: Also I'm reading that this is the correct behavior, that we all should handle the dragOver event.. funny explanation http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html

Comment: Many thanks. Just for the record, you'll need to preventDefault() if you're listening for dragenter

Answer (score 2):

You can on Backbone add into view this code:

```
events: {
....
....
    "drop #picture" : "dropHandler",
    "dragover #picture" : "dragOver"
},


dropHandler: function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
....
....
},

dragOver: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```