# Backbone Drop Event Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a dashboard with two backbone Views.  One view contains a variety of drop zones, the other contains items that are `draggable="true"`.  However, these drop zones are not firing on `drop` events, yet they are firing on `dragenter` and `dragleave`.  Why is the drop event not firing?

Note:  The template that is being rendered contains the `.item-drop-zone` div elements

**The View containing the Drop Zones:**

```
Shopperater.Views.ModuleMedleyView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "div",
    className: "row",
    template: JST['modules/medley'],

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
    },

    events: {
        'dragenter .item-drop-zone' : 'highlightDropZone',
        'dragleave .item-drop-zone' : 'unhighlightDropZone',
        'drop .item-drop-zone' : 'dropTest'
    },

    dropTest: function(e) {
        console.log("dropped!")
    },

    highlightDropZone: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(e.currentTarget).addClass('item-drop-zone-highlight')
    },

    unhighlightDropZone: function(e) {
        $(e.currentTarget).removeClass('item-drop-zone-highlight')
    },

    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template({ }));
        return this;
    }

});
```

Comment: Try with `'drop .item-drop-zone'` because the `drop` event is fired on the element where the drop occurred at the end of the drag operation.

Comment: Yes, I started with that and it still doesn't fire.  I'll edit this question to reflect your suggestion though.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14349610/877472) help at all?

Comment: No, I've been studying it for the last hour :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to tell the browser that the element is a drop target:

```
events: {
    'dragenter .item-drop-zone' : 'highlightDropZone',
    'dragleave .item-drop-zone' : 'unhighlightDropZone',
    'drop .item-drop-zone' : 'dropTest',
    'dragover .item-drop-zone': function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_Operations#droptargets for more information about drop targets. You need both `dragenter` and `dragover` events. Since you are already doing the `dragenter`, you can just add the `dragover`.

From the link

> Calling the `preventDefault` method during both a `dragenter` and `dragover`
>   event will indicate that a `drop` is allowed at that location.